# Get the content of range of cells

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I want to get the header row of an excel file :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    B    V
```

I am using an Execute SQL Task :

[image]

[image]

And to insert `Col1 Col2 Col3` :

[image]

[image]

This is the variable I am using :

[image]

When I query my destination table :

```
select * from dbo.demo
```

I get only Col1 instead of `Col1 Col2 Col3` :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return type is Single Row on your first Execute SQL Task. That means each element will be addressed by a zero based ordinal system.

Your variable `Headers` *is* column A *is* Ordinal/Result Name 0

Create 3 variables. ColA, ColB, ColC. Map to Ordinal 0, 1, 2

Modify Headers to be built on an expression and then use something like

```
@[User::ColA] + " " + @[User::ColB] + " " @[User::ColC]
```

That will create a space concatenated value that you can then push into your table

Comment: And if the number of my column headers is changing ? How can I achieve it dynamically?

Comment: That's a very different question and solution. The "low rent" approach would be to create ColA to ColUpperBound whether that's ColZ or ColXFD and then concatenate everything. Otherwise, you have to work with the Excel Object Model to identify what _is_ the range of populated data and then bring that back and if you're doing that, might as well concatenate it all together and assign to the `Headers` variable. The challenge with the object model approach is you are going to need to install additional libraries to make it work. And an actual install, not just nuget b/c those don't get saved